# Calculate difference between dates and start timer count from that result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a date in the following format: date: "2020-02-03T10: 00: 00";

Is there a way to calculate the difference between the current time - 2020-02-03T10: 00: 00?

Then I intend to start a timer that starts counting from the result. If the result is 30, I want the timer to start at 00:30:00, if it is 60, start 01:00:00.

Can someone help me?

[BLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xawnxw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

```
data = [
    {
      date: "2020-02-03T10:00:00",
    },
  ];

  start(){
     this.interval = setInterval(() => {
     this.display = Date.now() - parseInt(this.data[0].date);
     console.log(this.display)

          }, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your String `date: "2020-02-03T10:00:00"` to a Date Object in order to calculate the difference.

You can use `new Date(dateString)`. An example could be:

```
data = [
{
  date: "2020-02-03T10:00:00",
},
];

start(){
 this.interval = setInterval(() => {
 var date2 = new Date(this.data[0].date)
 this.display = Date.now() - date2;
 console.log(this.display)

      }, 1000);
}
```

Mind that the result is the difference in milliseconds.

Comment: The time format is not displayed correctly, but thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: @Harry It IS displayed correctly. As I said, it's in milliseconds. For me it's 14:00 right now. The Date from data is 10:00. Trying the code, I get `14377876`, which is 240 minutes, which is 4 hours.

Comment: I add a datepipe and perfect ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something you want to have in your function.
Tested and working: :)

```
    let difference = (+Date.now()) - (+new Date(this.data[0].date)) / 1000;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      difference--; // difference++ for increasing values if wanted to count in different way
      const s = Math.floor(difference / 1) % 60;
      const m = Math.floor(difference / 60) % 60;
      const h = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60)) % 24;
      this.display = `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
    }, 1000);
```

first convert to timestamp both dates. Substract and get difference and divide it by 1000 to get seconds. On each inteval decrease seconds by 1. Afterwards, get hours (`const h`), minutes(`const m`) and seconds(`const s`) by using formula above.
Print out in display(`this.display`) prop.

Comment: The problem is that the count is regressing instead of increasing and the time difference is not correct, but it was very close to what I intend to achieve! Thank you so much for trying to help me!

Comment: If you want to increase time just change to `difference++;` and also you should work with UTC dates in order to have it correct. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a good library for this.

Here is an example for your purpose:

```
//  Get date from string

var date = moment("2020-02-03T10:00:00");
var now = moment();

//  Get diference in milliseconds --> https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/07-difference/

var diference = now.diff(date, 'miliseconds');

//  Timeout in milliseconds --> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, diference);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manipulate dates using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) library, like :

```js
const data = [{
  date: '2020-02-03T14:00:00',
}];

this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  const [d] = data;

  this.display = moment() - moment(d.date);

  console.log(this.display);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The displayed result is the difference in milliseconds. So if you want seconds, divide the result by `1000`. Negative number will say the date is in the future, positive that it's in the past.

Comment: On stackblitz, I tried to apply this but it didn't work properly :(